# Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure

Whilst installing a plug-in earlier, I was advised to set 'WP_DEBUG' to false. However, as soon as I did so, I received this message when trying to load the site:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): An attempt was made to
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1531
>
> Error establishing a database connection
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database
>   server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is
>   down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
>
> Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
>
> Are you sure that the database server is running?
>
> If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact
>   your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress
>   Support Forums.

I've closely checked, and all of the database info is correct. I've also searched high and low all afternoon and cannot figure out what's causing the error in the connection.

Please help!

Comment: Just looking through some older unanswered SO posts and wanted to see if this is still an issue. Are you running a WordPress instance locally or a hosted instance in Azure? Providing some resources that might help: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29046202/mysqli-real-connect-HY000-2002-Connection-refused.html https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,646735,646735#msg-646735 This error usually is generated because the database isn't running or the error is generated during a restart of App + MySQL and the connection attempt is made when MySQL isn't fully running.